# Standardized residuals GARCH models

Tags: time-series, variance, references, garch, volatility-forecasting

Lets say I have a GARCH(1,1) model,

First, I model the conditional MEAN,

$$Y_t=\delta+\beta Y_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t$$

NextI gather the residuals $\varepsilon_t$ and model the conditional variance,

$$h_t=\omega + \alpha_i\varepsilon_{t-1}^2+\beta_ih_{t-1}$$

I need to get the standard residuals,

my attempt at this is,

$$U_t=\varepsilon_t/\sqrt{h_{t}}$$

Is this correct?

I am struggling to find this in any textbooks or papers so a reference would be appreciated if possible!

Comment: Thanks Richard, yes!

Comment: Indeed, when we talk about standardization, we are talking about "uniforming" the standard deviations. $\sqrt{r_t}$ is as good of an approximation for it as we can get (unless the process actually follows an exact GARCH, which never happens)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct.

References:

- Tsay ["Analysis of Financial Time Series"](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Analysis+of+Financial+Time+Series%2C+3rd+Edition-p-9780470414354) (3rd ed., 2010) p. 122; refer back to definition of ARCH(m) model (equation 3.5) on p. 116.
- Zivot & Wang ["Modelling Financial Time Series with S-PLUS"](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387279657) (2nd ed., 2006) p. 235.
- Francq & Zakoian ["GARCH Models"](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9780470670057) (2010) p. 335, 268.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: @FrancisOrigi, You are welcome!